# Why is my shower drain blocked for several minutes before draining?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

Every day when I have a shower, the drain starts out plugged.  The water from my shower will slowly fill the tub.  After about a minute or 2 the drain will unblock itself and the water will all drain out normally.  The tub will stay unblocked for the rest of the shower, but will return for my next shower.  This has happened for every shower that I've had for the past month or so.

Why is this happening?  Is something wrong with the plumbing?

Comment: It sounds more like the VENT is plugged (or missing) than the drain itself.

Comment: I can't see a vent holding back an entire tub of water (and why is it a temporary problem?). Strabbi, try to determine if the tub drains slowly at first or not at all. Shut the water off before it lets loose and see what's happening. Could be a helpful clue.

Comment: @jwh20 There's a lot of misinformation out there, but blocked vents do not cause slow drains. Before you quote the inverted soda bottle analogy, note that there is no such thing as a plumbing fixture with only one way in/out like a soda bottle - every plumbing fixture ever made is open to the air on top. Air does not need to "switch places" with water coming down the pipe - if the air doesn't have anywhere to go, the water doesn't, either. Vents are there to prevent P-trap siphoning, not to make the drain run faster.

Comment: The pressure on the drainage system depends only on the elevation of the water in the tub -- a cylinder of water right on top of the drain exerts the same pressure as the entire tub filled to the same depth. It could be interesting to make a water column around the drain and pour water into it manually. Absent the sounds of running and splashing water, one could listen to and observe the drainage. A piece of large-diameter pipe, a cylindrical food container with the ends cut off, etc could contain the water in a column so that a gallon or less of water is needed.

Comment: @NuclearWang I believe you are making assumptions beyond what is stated in the OP's question.  I see no indication that this is a "slow" drain.

Comment: @jwh20 By "slow drain", I mean that the water is draining slower than usual, or not at all, which is exactly what the OP describes. Regardless of the terminology, a blocked vent does not stop or slow water going down the drain. I don't see any way for the vent to be at all related to this issue.

Comment: The water does drain very slowly before it lets go, and then afterwards it speeds up, but it still doesn't sound like as much water as could flow is draining.

Comment: Reading the "Hot Network Questions", this may be related. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131591/slow-drain-after-tub-to-shower-conversion?rq=1

Comment: what kind of drain is this? do you have a stopper? This could be dried hair, blocked vents, partially clogged drain, your hot shower water might be loosening the clog. Many suggestions here, but if you can post some pictures or more info, it can help.

Comment: turn the shower off for 30 seconds, then turn back on ... does the symptom repeat?

Comment: If your drain plug is an internal (to the plumbing) lever-activated, it may well be stuck  partially "closed" and just happen to pop open now and then.   I would start by pulling the stopper and/or grating and snaking out the drain line as best you can.